# Dynamically manage key parsing in a YAML file with Python

Tags: python-3.x, yaml

I have a YAML file that needs parsing in Python; it is the skeleton of an Ansible inventory file that could change on a daily basis; I'm writing the parser that would build that inventory file.

Say I have this yaml file:

```
---
all:
  server1: ipaddr1
  server2: ipaddr2
  server3: ipaddr3
dbservers:
  server2
  server3
webgwservers:
  server1
```

I've the following code snippet to load the YAML:

```
    environment = yaml.load(bom, Loader=yaml.SafeLoader)

        for x in environment.keys():
        key = environment[x]
        if type(key) is list:
            print(x+ ":")
            if x == 'all':
                for xx in environment['all']:
                    for k,v in xx.items():
                        print(k+":"+v)
            if x == 'infra':
```

Now, I want to be able to list all top-level keys ('all', 'dbservers', 'webgwservers') and according to their type (lists, dicts, etc), do something. The thing is, I might had data to the yaml -- more top-level keys.

I thus need a way to parse the top-level keys and have their names, without hardcoding those key names.

Comment: I'm still not sure what you're trying to do. Can you provide an example where your snipper of code doesn't do what you want?

Comment: @MustafaQuraish I've updated the code snippets, above.
You see those `if x == 'all'` and `if x == 'infra'` lines ? I need to get rid of these and have them replaced with variables. The top-level keys all, infra, dbservers might be replaced and others added depending whether I'm in Prod, Preprod, QA, etc. My code shouldn't be aware in advance of the YAML file structure.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it, somehow, not in a much satisfactory way:

```
def createinventory(inputfile, outputfile, ansroot):
    with open(inputfile, 'r') as bom:
        environment = yaml.load(bom, Loader=yaml.SafeLoader)

        with open(ansroot + '/inventory/' + outputfile, 'w') as outfile:
            for keyname in environment.keys():
                if keyname != 'defaults' and keyname != 'dnszone':
                    key = environment[keyname]
                    #parseSubkeys(key, x, outfile)
                    outfile.write('[{}]\n'.format(keyname))
                    for xx in key:
                        for k, v in xx.items():
                            outfile.write('{}\t\tansible_host={}\n'.format(k, v))
                    outfile.write('\n')

    return 0
```

(This is not production code, of course)